# How to keep the status user in somewhere when he/she is online by asp.net core signalR?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm working on a chat project. When a user wants to log in and be online every time I fetch database and get all of the users and of course, I sign that user is online by connectionId. in fact, that user has a connectionId display in a view. As an online user and other users don't have a connectionId will display in view as an offline User.but my problem is when a user wants to be online I add a connectionId to the user and if another user wants to be online. A previous user is offline. My idea I keep every online user in a database, and if a user wants to leave the chat, I sign that user in a database as an offline user and vice-versa. What do you think about that? Is it wrong or lousy idea keeping the status of a user in a database?

[image]

```
public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            List<UsersViewModel> usersList = new List<UsersViewModel>();
            var claimIdenity = Context.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            var userId = claimIdenity.Claims.FirstOrDefault
                (x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;


            var users = await _dbContext.Users.ToListAsync();
            foreach (var user in users)
            {
                usersList.Add(new UsersViewModel
                {
                    UserId = user.Id,
                    FirstName = user.FirstName,
                    LastName = user.LastName,
                    PersonPicture = "https://devilsworkshop.org/files/2013/01/enlarged-facebook-profile-picture.jpg",

                });
            }


            UsersViewModel loginedUser = usersList.Where(u => u.UserId == userId).FirstOrDefault();
            if (loginedUser != null)
            {
                loginedUser.ConnectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
            }
            string jsonUsers = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(usersList);
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("GetAllUsers", jsonUsers);
            await base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }
```

Comment: Since chats are more real-time and a connected user is determined by whether they are connected to the system, I would expect the connection status to live in the runtime memory of the server. Databases are usually for persisting changes. E.g. if you shut down the server, all connections are lost, so it doesn’t make sense for the database to keep saying that someone is connected at that point. – That being said, this question is not really a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @poke, Thanks poke for your answer, but do you have any idea how to keep the status of a user.

Comment: You can use OnDisconnectedAsync For keeping it updated in DB. It also triggers if the browser for example is closed.  Can you tell me how you solved it at the end?